# How to draw a circle with a gap in c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, draw, picturebox, geometry

I am currently trying to display a circle in c# which is cut(has a gap and it's not finished). Is it possible to do this in c# directly or do I need to use some kind of photoshop?

An example of how it should look like is here :

[image: circles]

I am trying to utilise this in order to code a program for medical diagnosis. The Circle with gap will increase in size or decrease. Thanks!

Comment: mm, I'll look into it and report back. thnks.

Comment: May be the simplest way is to draw one black circle with appropriate pen thinkness, and then draw a small white rectangle to form a gap?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, that's an option will try it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably mean this:

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 8), new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100), 10, 340);
        }
```

The last 2 values(10 and 340 in this case),are the start angle and sweep angle.

EDIT:

To place the flat like ending fill a rectangle on top with the forms backcolor:

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 10), new Rectangle(50, 50, 100,100),10, 340);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), new Rectangle(142, 85, 14, 30));
        }
```

For the other ones you will have to play with the coordinates:).